# Accessing private gitlab repos over NPM in Elastic beanstalk: Host key verification failed

Tags: amazon-web-services

### Background

Repos:

- `myrepo`, in self-hosted gitlab server, in private repo with (tested) [deploy keys](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys)
- `mainrepo`, in self-hosted gitlab server, in private repo that works fine.

Its package.json references `myrepo` like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "myrepo": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.myhost.com:myusernamespace/myrepo.git"
}
```

The `mainrepo` is deployed to an AWS Elastic beanstalk instance without any problems.

### Problem

The problem is the build process on the Elastic beanstalk instance is failing, as it doesn't have permissions to access the gitlab server

### Error details

In the AWS web UI log

```
2016-02-04 13:36:59 UTC+0000    ERROR   During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
2016-02-04 13:36:59 UTC+0000    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
2016-02-04 13:36:58 UTC+0000    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-111111f'. Aborting the operation.
2016-02-04 13:36:58 UTC+0000    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2016-02-04 13:36:58 UTC+0000    ERROR   [Instance: i-111111f] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh] command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install npm ERR! git clone git@gitlab.myhost.com:myusernamespace/myrepo.git Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/.npm/_git-remotes/git-git-myhost-com-myysername-myrepo-git-99d4209c'... npm ERR! git clone git@gitlab.myhost.com:myusernamespace/myrepo.git Host key verification failed. npm ERR! git clone git@gitlab.myhost.com:myusernamespace/myrepo.git fatal: Could not read from remote repository. npm ERR! git clone git@gitlab.myhost.com:myusernamespace/myrepo.git npm ERR! git clone git@gitlab.myhost.com:myysername/ref.
```

In `nodejs.log`:

```
353 error Host key verification failed.
353 error fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
353 error
353 error Please make sure you have the correct access rights
353 error and the repository exists.
```

### Previous work

To allow Gitlabs to serve the repos over ssh, I added a public ssh key to Gitlabs [deploy keys](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys) for the project (and validated keys with `git clone git@gitlab.myhost.com:myusernamespace/myrepo.git`)

Then to allow Elastic beanstalk access to Gitlab, I  added the same public key to the environment by creating `01_authorized_keys.config` in `ebextensions`:

```
files:
  /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      ssh-rsa AAAA{...the existing eb authorized_keys...} existing_authorized_keys_name
      ssh-rsa AAAA{...gitlab.pub...} me@myhost.com
```

But it failed :(

### Alternatives tried

Other things I tried:

- Setting up the keys by echoing them into `authorized_keys` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721846/npm-private-modules-how-can-i-install-my-private-modules-on-a-aws-beanstalk-ins/30801201#30801201)
- Adding the public key that was already in authorized_keys to Gitlabs deploy list.

## Assumptions

- `eb deploy` will use ebextensions even if they are not
- I should be adding the public key to the EB instance
- I've not setup another test instance to build the entire project with only the gitlab deploy keys, so I am assuming if the gitlab deloy keys work manually, they will work through npm.